# How to not overlap components using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I created a component named **Header** with a simple css class:

```
<template>
      <nav
    class="flex fixed w-full items-center justify-between px-6 h-16 bg-white text-gray-700 border-b border-gray-200 z-10"
  >
        <!-- Etc... -->
    </nav>
```

In **Home** component I registred Header but it is overlapping the home:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Header />
    <div class="flex m-5">
      <h3>Hello</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    Header: () => import('@/components/Header.vue')
  }
}
</script>
```

The `Hello` is behind, even including `block class` in Home component is not worked. Anyone can helped?

Comment: What do you mean by "overlapping home"? Show screen or codebox

Comment: In this case, I have a string `Welcome HomePage` in Home Component, which is being overlapping with Header Component

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways you could achieve this, but building on the code you already have, you could:

1. Add a `top-0` class to your header. This will ensure that your header which is now positioned `fixed` will stick to the top of the viewport.
2. Add a top padding class equavliant to the height of your header (e.g. `pt-16`) to your container.

Here's a [live demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/SZ2JDLz9RX) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

overlapping component each others because of height of your component and in flex height taking automaticly so remove your height

remove  css `h-16`